# Extract Sub string from String using Regex

Tags: python, regex, shell, extract

i have a requirement, i need to extract substring from String using regex.

for example, here is my sample data:

```
Hello, "How" are "you" What "are" you "doing?"
```

from this example data, i need to extract only second and fourth occurrence of double quoted data.

my requirement is : `you doing?`

i tried with below regex but i am unable to extract as per my requirement.

```
"(.*?)"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `re.findall` and then slice the result to get the first and third matches:

```
import re

string = 'Hello, "How" are "you" What "are" you "doing?"'
result = re.findall('".+?"', string)[1::2]

print(result)
```

Here, the regex matches any number of characters contained within double quote marks, but tries to match as few as possible (a *non-greedy* match), otherwise we would end up with one single match, `"How" are "you" What "are" you "doing?"`.

Output:

```
['"you"', '"doing?"']
```

If you want to combine them without the quote marks, you can use `str.strip` along with `str.join`:

```
print(' '.join(string.strip('"') for string in result))
```

Output:

```
you doing?
```

An alternative method would be to just split on `"`:

```
result = string.split('"')[1::2][1::2]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['you', 'doing?']
```

This works because, if you separate the string by double quote marks, then the output will be as follows:

1. Everything before the first double quote
2. Everything after the first double quote and before the second
3. Everything after the second double quote and before the third
   ...

This means that we can take every even element to get the ones that are in quotes. We can then just slice the result again to get the 2nd and 4th results.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response @gmds , any idea about regex? actually i need to use this in nifi processor

Comment: @user6325753 What do you mean? It does use a regex.

Comment: i mean without using *re* is it possible?

Comment: "[^"]+"[^"]+("[^"]+")

Comment: @user6325753 I edited my answer to include a non-regex result.

Comment: @Tibrogargan That works too. You could post that as an answer.

Comment: @Tibrogargan Ah, I get it. You should post your solution as an answer then.

Answer (score 1):

Regex only solution.  May not be 100% accurate since it matches every second occurrence rather than just the 2nd and 4th, but it works for the example.

```
"[^"]+"[^"]+("[^"]+")
```

Demonstration in JS:

```js
var str = 'Hello, "How" are "you" What "are" you "doing?"';
var regex = /"[^"]+"[^"]+("[^"]+")/g
match = regex.exec(str);
while (match != null) {
   // matched text: match[0]
   // match start: match.index
   // capturing group n: match[n]
  console.log(match[1])
  match = regex.exec(str);
}
```

Comment: it extracts up to two double quoted strings, my requirement is only fetch 2 nd  and 4 th occurence

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that.  It matches every 2nd quoted string.  Yes, if there are only two it will match one and if there are more than five it will match three or more.  Since your question does not actually give any other requirements than the example you show, it does fulfill the problem.  Perhaps you need to be more specific

Comment: this regex not extracting second quoted string, extracts upto second quoted string. i need only second and fourth occurrence of double quoted string

Comment: I think you're maybe confusing the terms `match` and `group`, or perhaps not using the global flag.  See demo I just added.

Answer (score 0):

We can try using `re.findall` to extract all quoted terms.  Then, build a string using only even entries in the resulting list:

```
input = "Hello, \"How\" are \"you\" What \"are\" you \"doing?\""
matches = re.findall(r'\"([^"]+)\"', input)
matches = matches[1::2]
output = " ".join(matches)
print(output)

you doing?
```